# Group similar numbers of a vector

Tags: r

Let's say that I have the following vector:

`c(4, 5, 5, 8, 12, 12, 12, 13, 15, 15, 18, 19, 20, 23, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 41)`

and I would like to "group" its elements according to their value: numbers that differ <=3 should be considered to belong to the same group.
In this case I would like, for each number appearing in the vector, to get all the numbers that are close to it. 
For example,

```
4  -->  c(4,5,5,8)
5  -->  c(4,5,5,8)
8  -->  c(5,8)
12 -->  c(12,12,12,13,15,15)
```

etc

Possibly, it could be useful to get also their index... 
Is there any smart way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this little function:

```
similar <- function(vec, val, bound = 3, index = F) {
    close.index <- which(abs(vec - val) <= bound)
    if (index) return(close.index)
    return(vec[close.index])
}

x <- c(4, 5, 5, 8, 12, 12, 12, 13, 15, 15, 18, 19, 20, 23, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 41)
similar(x, 5)
# [1] 4 5 5 8
similar(x, 5, index = T)
# [1] 1 2 3 4
similar(x, 5, bound = 7)
# [1]  4  5  5  8 12 12 12
```

Comment: wouldn't hurt to modify:  `return(list(sim=vec[close.index], index=close.index))`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not the most elegant version, but does this do what you wanted to have?

```
x <- c(4, 5, 5, 8, 12, 12, 12, 13, 15, 15, 18, 19, 20, 23, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 41)
vals <- unique(x)
# print indices
for (i in 1:length(vals)) print(which((x >= vals[i] - 3) & (x <= vals[i] + 3)))
# print values
for (i in 1:length(vals)) print(x[which((x >= vals[i] - 3) & (x <= vals[i] + 3))])

[1] 1 2 3
[1] 1 2 3 4
[1] 2 3 4
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
[1]  9 10 11 12 13
[1] 11 12 13
[1] 11 12 13 14
[1] 13 14
[1] 15 16 17 18 19
[1] 20

[1] 4 5 5
[1] 4 5 5 8
[1] 5 5 8
[1] 12 12 12 13 15 15
[1] 12 12 12 13 15 15
[1] 12 12 12 13 15 15 18
[1] 15 15 18 19 20
[1] 18 19 20
[1] 18 19 20 23
[1] 20 23
[1] 37 37 37 37 37
[1] 41
```

it is indeed a little bit more elegant to use `abs`.

```
for (i in 1:length(vals)) print(which(abs(x-vals[i]) <= 3))
for (i in 1:length(vals)) print(x[which(abs(x-vals[i]) <= 3)])
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short solution giving you all the group as a list:

```
x = c(4, 5, 5, 8, 12, 12, 12, 13, 15, 15, 18, 19, 20, 23, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 41)

m = unique(x)
setNames(apply(abs(outer(m,m,'-')), 2, function(u) m[u<=3]),m)

#$`4`
#[1] 4 5

#$`5`
#[1] 4 5 8

#$`8`
#[1] 5 8

#$`12`
#[1] 12 13 15

#$`13`
#[1] 12 13 15

#$`15`
#[1] 12 13 15 18

#$`18`
#[1] 15 18 19 20

#$`19`
#[1] 18 19 20

#$`20`
#[1] 18 19 20 23

#$`23`
#[1] 20 23

#$`37`
#[1] 37

#$`41`
#[1] 41
```

For the index, the same concept can be applied easily:

```
setNames(apply(abs(outer(m,m,'-')), 2, function(u) which(x %in% m[u<=3])),m)
```

Comment: best solution so far. `outer` is some powerful stuff. +1

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to create lists with the numbers as "keys":

```
data <- c(4, 5, 5, 8, 12, 12, 12, 13, 15, 15, 18, 19, 20, 23, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 41)
uniques <- unique(data)

myGroups <- lapply(
  uniques,
  function(n) Filter(
    function(x) abs(x - n) <= 3,
    data
  )
)
names(myGroups) <- uniques


myIndices <- lapply(
  uniques,
  function(n) which(abs(data - n) <= 3)
)
names(myIndices) <- uniques
```

Then, to access the group and indices for '12', say:

```
> myGroups[['12']]
[1] 12 12 12 13 15 15
> myIndices[['12']]
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10
```